# Facebook comment with image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to infer whether a comment on Facebook has a photo/image attached (using the graph API)? For example, a comment with this id:

`10153245215739574_10153245218744574`

has a photo but when querying this object, no field seem to give away if the comment has a photo attached:

`{
  "id": "10153245215739574_10153245218744574", 
  "from": {
    "id": "1377902372514543", 
    "name": "Alecsander Ferreira"
  }, 
  "message": "QUEEN <3", 
  "can_remove": false, 
  "created_time": "2015-02-22T05:21:16+0000", 
  "like_count": 2037, 
  "user_likes": false
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying the object without explicitly stating the fields will only provide the default fields. You need to request the field you need.

For example

`10153245215739574_10153245218744574?fields=attachment`

```
{
  "attachment": {
    "type": "photo", 
    "title": "", 
    "target": {
      "id": "1407980226173424", 
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1407980226173424&set=p.1407980226173424&type=1"
    }, 
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1407980226173424&set=p.1407980226173424&type=1", 
    "media": {
      "image": {
        "height": 720, 
        "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/11021095_1407980226173424_823555107490491827_n.jpg?oh=96e50bb93269d6e69067a8b3ebf98292&oe=558E78CF", 
        "width": 531
      }
    }
  }, 
  "id": "10153245215739574_10153245218744574"
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Could you please point me to a list of available fields?